# What is the need of name and value when making a form

Tags: html

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male<br>
```

What is the need of adding the **name** and **value** here.The code gives same output without and with it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask and how to format questions

Comment: The name and value is sent as `gender=male` to the server when the form is submitted - google "form tutorial" http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php

Comment: This is basic HTML. I think you should have googled your question a bit before posting it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

**Value Attribute:**: The value to be used as it is. Without specifying the value attribute your code would work, because it would return "true". However when the value attribute is set, it would explicitly return that value.

**Name Attribute:**
The value of the element is sent under the "name" attribute when sent to server, in most of the Web Development Frameworks. Also name attribute groups the elements on client side, i.e.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />

<input type="radio" name="education" value="Graduate" />
<input type="radio" name="education" value="Undergraduate" />
```

If you don't group the radio buttons, you can select only 1 from all 4. However, we have grouped them with logical names and that is why we can select 1 from gender and 1 from education group.